# Creating an gauge chart in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, charts, highcharts

I need to create the chart in angular 4 app like in mockup:
[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u56hw.png)

So which library do I need to use to create such a chart? Before the question i saw all libraries but i did not find something that looked like this mockup.

Comment: You get down voted because your question is off-topic. Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce the chart that looks exactly the same as your mockup using **Highcharts solid gauge series**: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid

---

### Edit

Here are few things that need to be done:

- set proper value for `pane.startAngle` and `pane.endAngle`
- configure the style and values of ticks (`tickPositions` option
  can be used for irregular tick positions)
- change `innerRadius` and `outerRadius` to make the pane thinner
- use the coloring solution from this post:
  [Highcharts solid gauge, show colors of previous stops in gauge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005522/highcharts-solid-gauge-show-colors-of-previous-stops-in-gauge/47014263#47014263)

Comment: but how i can do this... i didnt see the same examples